# I have a piece of python code and i have defined the object but it will not recognise

Tags: python

this is the code

```
def startgame ():
    print ("welcome to the game type start to continue")

print
prompt_sta ()
#the error is here
def prompt_sta ():
    prompt_sta = raw_input ("Enter a command: ")


startgame ()
prompt_sta
```

Comment: You call `prompt_sta` before you define it.

Comment: This does not deserve to be downvoted or closed. It's true that this is a very easily solved question, but it is clear, objective and programming related.

Comment: And shows no research effort, you forgot that.

Comment: thx all i'm new to coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the function definition to the top of your file.  It *must* be defined before you can use it.  In your posted code, when you try to call **prompt_sta**, it hasn't yet been defined.

Also note that your use at the bottom is missing parentheses to be a proper call.  That statement does nothing.

```
def prompt_sta ():
    prompt_sta = raw_input ("Enter a command: ")

def startgame ():
    print ("Welcome to the game!  Type start to continue")

print
prompt_sta()
# The error is here

startgame()
prompt_sta()
```